# Would this function for deep cloning an object do the job?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

It's just for my own usage. I don't want it for a library or framework. So it doesn't has to be hundred percent bullet-proof.

Parameter: Object to clone.

Return: Copy of the assigned object.

```
function cloneObject(obj) {
    var ret = {};
    var cloneArray = function(arr) {
      var ret = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
          cloneArray(arr[i]);
        } else {
          ret[i] = arr[i];
        }
      }

      return ret;
    }

    obj = obj || {}

    for (var i in obj) {            
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {      
        // In case of property is an array.
        if (Array.isArray(obj[i])) {
          ret[i] = cloneArray(obj[i]);
        } else if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
          // Recursive call in case of sub objects.         
          ret[i] = cloneObj(obj[i]);                  
        } else if (typeof obj[i] == 'function') {           
          ret[i] = obj[i].bind(ret);
        } else {
          // In case of primitive datatypes             
          ret[i] = obj[i];                
        }
      }           
    }
    // Return a reference to the new object.
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: You should ask this on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ;)

Comment: Cool. :) Big thank you for the link.

Comment: Well, what bullets are you going to shoot with? When you ask whether it "*does the job*", you'll need to describe the job. Otherwise we'll punch hundreths of holes in it.

Comment: No, it won't do the job even for a simple usage. It doesn't work for arrays, and auto-binding methods will not go well.

Comment: @Bergi I've enhanced the function so that the array problem should be solved. I would be pleased if you have a look. Moreover: Please give me a hint concerning the auto-binding issue.

Comment: I think a cloning function should not try to "clone" functions (doesn't work in general anyway, e.g. with closures) at all. Rather treat them like primitives, or handle them on a per-case basis if you need it. Calling `.bind(ret)` is probably worse than just copying the reference.

Comment: Many thanks for your answers. I really appreciate it.